# Child view controllers not scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have created a UI which has two child view controllers which slide in as menus from each side of the screen when a button is pressed (think hamburger menu). I have a table view on one and a collection view on the other. Neither will scroll for me or accept touch events. The code below is used to add to the parent container.

```
    sidePanel = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("sidePanel")
    self.addChildViewController(sidePanel)
    self.view.addSubview(sidePanel.view)
    sidePanel.view.center.x += self.view.frame.size.width
    sidePanel.view.frame.size.width = 250
    sidePanel.view.updateConstraints()
    sidePanel.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Any ideas why touch isn't working? I've checked all the obvious solutions (userInteractionEnabled etc.).

Comment: `sidePanel.view.frame.size.width = 250` never works ,show more info ,your question is not clear

Comment: @WilsonXJ This is the only piece of code. The rest is in a storyboard. It is a Container View which separate 'sidePanel' controllers are added to. I've removed the line you mentioned with the same results so you're right it's not necessary.

Comment: you can't change `width` direct to `UIView` , it needs you to change the frame like `var rect = sidePanel.view.frame`  `rect.size.width = 250`  `sidePanel.view.frame = rect`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by moving the view. The sidePanel is not contained within the view so is not receiving touch events.